# Count and pick top three in sqlite

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I have table in db who called answers and i need to get the top 3 usernames who answered the most correct answers and show their username and how much they correct

I am using sqlite

```
table: answers
Game_id ,Username ,Question_id ,Answer ,Is_correct ,Answer_Time

in Is_correct category 1 is correct and 0 is not correct
Example:
username    Is_correct
AA          1
AA          0
AB          0
AC          1
AC          1
AD          1
AD          1
AD          1
AD          0
the result will  be 
AD 3
AC 2
AA 1

i try this but it didn't work 
SELECT USERNAME,SUM(IS_CORRECT) FROM T_PLAYERS_ANSWERS ORDER BY SUM(IS_CORRECT) DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `GROUP BY` clause. The correct query is:

```
SELECT username, SUM(is_correct) as total FROM t_players_answers
    GROUP BY username ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: it dosent work, this give me only one username and the username with no answers

Comment: @dor: It worked on my tests directly with the sqlite command line tool...

Comment: I'm sorry my mistake your answer was good there was problem with my code thanks a lot